# How to click LI's using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I've only scraped static pages using Nokogiri. I've never tried automation, and I'm currently seeing if Mechanize can do what I need.

Assuming I'm already on the search results page for a city in Yelp, I'm trying to click a few items using Mechanize. The goal is to get to the WiFi section which is somewhat deep in the filters.

After some troubleshooting, I think I realized the problem is that the parse isn't showing the LI that I need to click. I think Mechanize can handle things like links and forms, but will it be able to click on a LI?

Here's what I'm using:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&ns=1')

all_filters = agent.page.at('.all-filters-toggle')

p agent.click(all_filters)
```

This is giving me a list of what appears to be all the links on the page. I noticed it jumps from the blue "Category" items into the search results list. In other words, the Filters are skipped.

1. Is there a way to do this with Mechanize?
2. Is the code above somewhat correct? I figure the result of print it out should be the entire page, including the newly-toggled items.

Here's some steps to come afterwards in order to reach the WiFi search:

```
# search a city based on user input
# click on All Filters (list item)
# click on More Features (link)
# click on Wi-Fi (link)
# select both Free and Paid (checkboxes)
# click Search (button/form?)
# store results
```

Comment: You do know that Yelp has an [API](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview), which should remove the need to scrape their pages, right?

Comment: @theTinMan I'm new to API's but took a peek at theirs before going the scraping route. I couldn't find anything in terns of filters (WiFi). Would value any tips/direction if you happen to see it.

Comment: I'd send a note to their API support. It's always better to see what they support first. You can also get their code, figure out how to add it if it's not already there and submit a pull request. It's only as a final resort that you should revert to scraping. Scraping is slower, more likely to break, and more likely to run afoul of their terms of service causing your code to be banned.

Comment: @theTinMan I didn't know API's were that flexible and approachable. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: APIs are _supposed_ to offer the same data as a UI in a standardized manner. They're faster and use less CPU than rendering a UI or scraping. If they don't have a way of getting to the data you want, then they should and there's your opportunity to get what you want via a more robust method.